# Tarball data seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time

Tags: reactjs, npm, togetherjs

I've been debugging this for almost a week and I havent really solved it. Can someone help mo on this one. I already uninstalled and reinstalled my node and it always comes up.

Also tried

```
npm cache clean --force
rm -rf ~/.npm
```

But this doesnt solve the problem either.

`npm WARN tarball tarball data` for `esprima@https://github.com/ariya/esprima/tarball/master (sha1-C0XMQgDkwwAPPkY1H9aa+FeCIPo=)`
seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.

Comment: How did you fix it?